# Sqlite error (missing database) while trying to update jtable

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, netbeans

```
private void checkKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    try{
        String ch ="select * from check where name like ?%";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(ch);
        pst.setString(1, check.getText());
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
        checker.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

above is the code im using, and im getting a:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "check": syntax error)
```

i have a table named check in sqlite, and im trying to create a search engine in my jframe, so when i enter text in a textfield the jtable filters automatically. any idea why this error could come about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this part, if you need to pass % you have to pass it with set Method and as check is a reserved keyword in sqlite change it to `check`

```
 String ch ="select * from check where name like ?%";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(ch);
        pst.setString(1, check.getText());
```

with

```
  String ch ="select * from `check` where name like ?";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(ch);
        pst.setString(1, check.getText()+"%");
```

Comment: CHECK is a keyword in sqlite

Comment: Ok try now, i modified the answer

Comment: omg, doh!, yep your right, just changed the table name to library, and it works now thanks for your help, im just starting out in programming :)

Comment: dont need the modified answer but i assume it will work and use this for future reference, thanks for your help.